# JQuery tokenfield with django not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-3.x, autocomplete

I am trying to incorporate a search field in a django registration form. I would like to use a bootstrap tokenfield that searches a django model for possible matches to the search string. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now. Here is my code below.

```html
<div class="form-inline" id="keywords_div">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <input type="text" name="search_text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" placeholder="Enter keyword" style="width: 50%" />
                                            <button type="button" id="addKeyword-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>


My JQuery code.
```

```js
 
 $(function(){
      //auto complete ajax code.
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
          autocomplete: {
            //source:['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
            delay: 100
          },
          showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
    }).keyup(function(){
        alert('key pressed');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/user_account/auto_complete_search/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#tokenfield').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)

            },
            dataType: 'text'
        });
    });
});
 
 });
```

Django View

```js
#This is the function that handle the auto complete search functionality.
def autocomplete_search_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    keywords = Keywords.objects.filter(keyword__icontains=search_text)
    #data = serializers.serialize('json', keywords, fields=('keyword'))

    return HttpResponse('Query completed', content_type='application/text')
```

user_account/urls.py

```js
url(r'^auto_complete_search/$', autocomplete_search_view, name='autocomplete_search'),
```

The error from the browser.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After a very long time of searching for the answer, I eventually got it right. see the code below. I'm trying to figure out how to make the dropdown menu scrollable but code below does exactly what I wanted.

```js
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
            source: function(request, response){
                        if(request.term.length >= 5){
                             $.ajax({
                                url: "/user_account/auto_complete_search/",
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    'search_text': request.term,
                                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                                },
                                success: function(data){
                                    if(data != ""){
                                        var dataArr = [];
                                        $.each(data, function(i, jsonObj){
                                            dataArr[i] = jsonObj.fields.keyword;
                                        });
                                        response(dataArr);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        response([]);
                                    }
                                },
                                dataType: 'json'
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            response([]);
                        }
                    },
            delay: 300,
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
```

Django view.

```js
#This is the function that handle the auto complete search functionality.
def autocomplete_search_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''
        return HttpResponse([{}], content_type='application/json')

    keywords = Keywords.objects.filter(keyword__icontains=search_text)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', keywords, fields=('keyword'))

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

The HTML is still the same. Hope this helps somebody in the future.